# Keep Bootstrap panels the same size independtly from content inside them

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple Bootstrap panels, but they all have *individual* height based on the content inside them.

Take a look at the picture, all the panels have unequal height. I want them to have a general height, and to be responsive too.

[image]

I've tried using:

```
min-height;
max-height;
heigth: x !important;
```

But none of them seems to work.

Here is my code:

```
.panel{
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 150px !important;
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

HTML (note that I'm adding 3 panels inside one row.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 p1" data-clickstate="0">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel_1">
                <div class="panel-body" style="display: inline" id="cat_1">

                    <div class="icono">
                        <img src="media/iconos/motores_busqueda.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="nombre-y-des">
                        <div>
                            <h5 class="nombre">Motores de búsqueda</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="des">
                            <p>Servicios de búqueda de páginas web.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel_2">
                <div class="panel-body" id="cat_2" style="display: inline">
                    <div class="icono">
                        <img src="media/iconos/navegadores.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="nombre-y-des">
                        <div>
                            <h5 class="nombre">Navegadores</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="des">
                            <p>Programa que permite navegar por internet, renderizado páginas HTML en contenido visual y
                                comprensible.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel_3">
                <div class="panel-body" id="cat_3" style="display: inline">
                    <div class="icono">
                        <img src="media/iconos/servidores_correo.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="nombre-y-des">
                        <div>
                            <h5 class="nombre">Servidores de correo</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="des">
                            <p>Servicio que permite enviar y recibir mensajes mediante sistemas de comunicación eletrónicos
                                en línea.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In addition to the answers you get, I think you should also make the icons the same height. Just so the text lines up with each other. This is just my opinion about the design.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, in fact I was just thinking of that. Ugh, the art team can't make anything good!

Comment: @dawn : I'm guessing that your panel are in fact the same height, but that what you are seeing is in fact the panel-body. You should apply the height to this class instead. I can't confirm without a working example but you should try this out.

Comment: @IronWIlliamCash it indeed helped, in fact it solved the problem, tho not on *.panel-body*. It worked on *.panel*.

Comment: @dawn : Glag I could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, guys, I found a simple way.

Reading @IronWilliamCash comment, I used:

```
height: xpx;
```

**Inside** *.panel* (it didn't worked in *.panel-body*).

And voila! All same height, and to keep them responsive just use *@media* queries.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .caracs{
    width: 500px !important;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    } 
.panel{
    text-align: center;
    height: 255px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
    .caracs{
    width: 810px !important;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    } 
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
    .caracs{
    width: 810px !important;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    }
    .panel{
        text-align: center;
        height: 165px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fiddle that may help you: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23594/

When the `height`-related properties are added on `.panel-body`, you can change the height of your panels to a fixed height, also, you have remove the css code: `display: inline;`

In the JSFiddle, I created another class for height fixing as follows:

```
.fixed-panel {
    min-height: 300px;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Can't you just use `height:500px` instead of `min-height:500px;max-height:500px;`. Don't they do the same thing?

Comment: Sorry for this confusion. I wrote both `min-height` and `max-height` to set them as different values, however I made some typo by setting them to the same value. Let me edit it right now :)

Comment: @SteffYang This is a good approach and does works. I too comment about the size of the icons, they keep making stuff unequal but, making them the same size, everything should work fine.

Comment: @dawn feels great that the answer does help you! :D